# Outlook ignores conditional comments when forwarding email

Tags: outlook, html-email, conditional-comments, email-forwarding

I have optimized an email for Outlook. A content with max-width gets hidden, while the another one (with a `set width=""` in `<td>`) shows up. That is working fine so far.

When this email gets forwarded in Outlook, Outlook seems to strip of or ignore the conditional comments, because in the forwarded version both contents are showing up (so that I get double pictures, which should definitely not be).

Has anyone had the same problem or knows what the issue is or why Outlook is ignoring the conditional comments? How can I fix this? Any ideas?

Comment: its something thats out of our control. Outlook bsically rewrites the email which shows everthing thats in the email, hidden or not. If you are using images for different screensizes then i suggest 1 and just resize for different devices.

Comment: I suggest using a different email client.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no influence on the email clients which our customers are using... ;)